# xslt condition and decimal values

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to compare two software versions using xsl, for example 1.13 and 1.4 and I want 1.13 to be larger than 1.4.

However, the following xslt condition will fail.

```
<xsl:if test="1.13 >= 1.4">
```

Instead I opted for an approacah where I remove the integer part using substring-after() so that only the remainder is used in the comparison (assuming that the integer part is the same for now).

```
<xsl:if test="substring-after(1.13, ".") >= substring-after(1.4, ".")">
```

(actually I had to write it like this)

```
<xsl:if test="substring-after(1.13, &quot;.&quot;) >= substring-after(1.4, &quot;.&quot;)">
```

That works for the values 1.13 and 1.4. However, when I compared the values 1.10 and 1.4, the comparison fails.

Is there a better way of doing this comparison?

Comment: Which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: And will all those version numbers you want to compare only have one dot separating digits or will there be longer sequences with several dots?

Comment: That would be v2

Comment: And yes, for the purpose of this question we can assume that only one separating dot is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what XSLT processor and version you are using. With Saxon, you can do

```
  <xsl:template match="/" name="main">
     <out>
       <xsl:value-of select="compare('1.13', '1.4', 'http://saxon.sf.net/collation?alphanumeric=yes')"/>
     </out>
  </xsl:template>
```

which returns 1 indicating that the first argument is considered greater than the second. You could also write

```
<xsl:if test="'1.13' < '1.4'" 
        default-collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?alphanumeric=yes"/>
```

If you don't want to be dependent on processor-dependent collation URIs, then in XSLT 3.0 you could use the fn:sort() function which allows you to provide a function to compute your own sort key, which in this case might be `tokenize($x, '\.')!xs:integer(.)`.

With earlier XSLT releases and no processor-dependent features, use xsl:sort with multiple sort keys computed using substring-before and substring-after.

Answer (score 2):

You can try converting the versions to strings or integers and then perform a comparison. E.g. version `1.13` will be converted to `0113` and version `1.4` will be converted to `0104` and then `0113` will be compared with `0104`.

Below XSLT uses XSLT 1.0 to perform the comparison for single `.` separator.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="Versions">
        <xsl:variable name="oldVersion">
            <xsl:call-template name="convert-ver-to-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="ver" select="OldVersion"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="newVersion">
            <xsl:call-template name="convert-ver-to-string">
                <xsl:with-param name="ver" select="NewVersion"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$newVersion &gt; $oldVersion">
                <Out>New greater than Old</Out>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Out>Old greater than New</Out>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="convert-ver-to-string">
        <xsl:param name="ver" />
        <xsl:variable name="updVer">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($ver, '.')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$ver" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($ver, '.0')" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-before($updVer, '.'), '00')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-after($updVer, '.'), '00')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample Input XML

```
<Versions>
    <OldVersion>1.3</OldVersion>
    <NewVersion>1.12</NewVersion>
</Versions>
```

Output

```
<Out>New greater than Old</Out>
```